# How to render state directly after setting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Introduction**: I am **very** new to ReactJS(*I just started a week ago*), but I am not using that as an excuse, so please go hard on me, if there is something that I am not understanding.

**Abstract**: I am trying to implement Protected Routes.

**Background**: Upon the Protected Route component mounting, `componentDidMount()` invokes a function called `isAuthenticated()` that changes the state of a field called, `isAuthenticated`. That same field is what I am checking for to determine whether the user sees the Protected Component or is routed back to the Login page.

**Issue**: Everytime I visit the Protected Route aka `CreatePost`, my logs show that `isAuthenticated()` is invoked after `componentDidMount()` but I am unsure why my UI is **not** reflecting those new changes, to show the user the authenticated route.

**Question**: Can anyone please assist or recommend a better strategy that I have not considered? I really appreciate it.

**Note**: If I declare the `this.state.isAuthenticated` field in my constructor to be true, I will see my Protected Route, but this is not my intended goal. Hope this is helpful in diagnosing the issue.

**App.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css'

import Signup from './components/Signup'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Feed from './components/Feed'
import CreatePost from './components/Createpost' 
import ProtectedRoute from './components/Protectedroute'

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Link,
    Route,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Link to ='/signup'>Signup</Link>
                    <br />
                    <Link to = '/login'>Login</Link>
                    <br />
                    <Link to ='/create-post'>Create Post</Link>
                    <br />
                    <Link to ='/feed'>Feed</Link>
                </div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path = '/signup' component = {Signup} />
                    <Route path = '/login' component = {Login} />
                    <Route path = '/feed' component = {Feed} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path = '/create-post' component = {CreatePost} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }

        this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('--componentDidMount--')
        this.isAuthenticated()
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        console.log('--isAuthenticated--')
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: true})
    }
    render() {
        const Component = this.props.component

        return this.state.isAuthenticated ? (<Component />) : (<Redirect to = '/login' />)
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

Comment: In addition to the comment below, you can move the logic of your isAuthenticated into your parent and pass it down as a prop to protected so your app re-renders when there is a state change but the source of your problem is the async nature of setState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting state inside the component for that api call try creating a function and then returning the api response as true or success

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    };

    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("--componentDidMount--");
    this.isAuthenticated();
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    console.log("--isAuthenticated--");
    // Authentiction logic
    return true;
  }
  render() {
    const Component = this.props.component;

    return (
      <Route
        render={props =>
          this.isAuthenticated() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem here that setState is async. What happens is that in the first render this.state.isAuthenticated is false and therefore immediately redirecting. You can introduce a loading state which will help you defer the rendering of the component \ redirecting to only after the state of both loading and isAuthenticated are settled.
In general never expect setState to change the state immediately in a synchronous way.